# How to trace "The operating system is not presently configured to run this application."?

Tags: windows, dll

I have a very old application which I need to run on a newer Windows system. And that application does not start with the dreaded:

> The operating system is not presently configured to run this application.

Googling for this problem brings up lots of very specific issues with specific apps and the solutions are just shots in the dark or super specific things with specific versions of Windows, Office, etc.

But I'd like to know if there is a way to trace the start-up of such applications to find out what specifically is wrong so I can fix it.

Most likely it's some DLLs are missing. On Unix I have ldd and I can find out what shared libraries they need and which ones are present vs. missing. Is there an ldd equivalent?

And is there some dtrace equivalent where, if the issue is not just a missing DLL, we can see where this error occurs more or less to get a clue what misconfiguration might exist?

EDIT: from the comments:

Some suggest to run in compatibility mode

> Have you tried running the program in Compatibility mode (Properties → Compatibility → Compatibility Mode)

> What is the application? Is it a 32-bit application? Please edit your question to include this information – Ramhound Jun 15 at 12:42

while the specific application should not matter to my question, what I wanted to establish is a way for me and other people to systematically diagnose such problems instead of this wild goose chase we usually have on Windows.

Of course we need to check if it's a 32-bit application trying to run on a 64-bit platform, I guess that may be one aspect of the compatibility mode.

> If it is a 32bit application try this http://dependencywalker.com/
> good lead! This might be the answer to my question.

> Run Process Monitor and look in that area for clues. Chances are greater than 90% that you will be out of luck and need to run your app in a virtual machine.
> I guess with the process monitor I will not have time to check because the application doesn't even start (if there is any process starting, it runs for only a split second.)

> Are you using the latest version of Windows 10
> I think we are on some Windows Server, and whatever version. But again, I am not issuing a "help request" to just get one more of these super specific answers. I suppose I am not asking for a fish but that someone who knows how to fish would teach us how to fish.

> Did you try to copy the launch command from the link and run it in a DOS prompt? Sometimes you have some printouts you could investigate.
> This is a very good idea, indeed that has helped me in the past.

Comment: Have you tried running the program in Compatibility mode _(Properties → Compatibility → Compatibility Mode)_

Comment: What is the application? Is it a 32-bit application?  Please [edit] your question to include this information

Comment: If it is a 32bit application try this>>>>https://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: Run Process Monitor and look in that area for clues. Chances are greater than 90% that you will be out of luck and need to run your app in a virtual machine

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Windows 10?

Comment: Did you try to copy the launch command from the link and run it in a DOS prompt? Sometimes you have some printouts you could investigate.